# Conditional expectation of max{Y,r} given Y < x

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conditional-expectation, game-theory

I have difficulties computing the following conditional expectation:
$$E[\max \{Y_1,r\}|Y_1 < x]$$
the CDF of $Y_1$ is G(`).

I browse other questions that deal with only one part of the conditional expectation, for instance, the expectation of max given min, or expectation of y given y<x. But I still find difficult to compute this one.

My thought is to separate this into 2 parts and add them by probability:
$$P(Y_1 \leq r)E[r|Y_1 < x]+P(Y_1>r)E[Y_1|Y_1 < x]=G(r)r+(1-G(r))[r+\frac{1}{G(x)}\int_{r}^{x}yf(y)dy  ]$$
Rearrange I get:
$$(1-G(r))[\frac{1}{G(x)}\int_{r}^{x}yf(y)dy]+r$$

But the correct answer is:
$$r\frac{G(r)}{G(x)}+\frac{1}{G(x)}\int_{r}^{x}yf(y)dy$$

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong and the right way to deal with this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$$ E[max\{Y,r\} | Y<x] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} max\{y,r\}f_Y (y|y<x)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{r} rf_Y (y|y<x)dy + \int_{r}^{x} yf_Y (y|y<x)dy $$

Now just let's figure out what is the new density function. Since the sample space is  reduced, the density function for y values which are less than x must be scaled properly. Let the new function be called

$$   g\left(y\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       a(x)f_Y(y) &  y<x\\
       0 &  otherwise
     \end{array}
   \right.\\
$$

We know that $ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(y)dy  = 1  $

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(y)dy =  \int_{-\infty}^{+x}a(x)g(y)dy = a(x)\int_{-\infty}^{+x}f_Y(y)dy  = a(x)G(x) = 1$$
So we have $ a(x) =\frac{1}{G(x)}   $
$$ g(y) = f_Y(y|y<x) = \frac{f_Y(y)}{G(x)} $$

Returning to the integrals we have $$ E[max\{Y,r\} | Y<x] = r\int_{-\infty}^{r} \frac{f_Y(y)}{G(x)}dy + \int_{r}^{x} y\frac{f_Y(y)}{G(x)}dy  = r\frac{G(r)}{G(x)} + \int_{r}^{x} y\frac{f_Y(y)}{G(x)}dy $$

Comment: Hi thank you so much! The general logic is very clear, just one thing is confusing me, in the first formula where you expand $max\{y,r\}$, why it equals $$ \int_{-\infty}^{r} rf_Y (y|y<x)dy + \int_{r}^{x} yf_Y (y|y<x)dy$$? Imagine if r is greater than y, then we should just have $$\int_{-\infty}^{r} rf_Y (y|y<x)dy$$, but now in this formula, the second part becomes negative, and we get something smaller than $$\int_{-\infty}^{r} rf_Y (y|y<x)dy$$